# Understanding what a tranformation on a Ray and Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, symmetry, hilbert-space

I've been referring to **Chapter 2** of *Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by **Weinberg**  where he talks about symmetries and how they go about. Now, there are two points that he mentions. A ray, which by his definition in **Section 2.2** is an equivalence class of vectors on a Hilbert space with norm 1 such that there is a $\theta$ and $\Psi_1 = e^{i\theta}\Psi'_1$

First, when he starts talking about symmetries on *Pg. 76*, he says. If $T_1$ is a transformation on a ray , $\mathcal{R}_1$ which takes it to $\mathcal{R}_2$ by the following action $T_1:\mathcal{R}_1\mapsto \mathcal{R}_2$ then by winger's theorem, this induces a unitary transformation on vectors on the Hilbert space $\Psi_1 \in R_1$ such that $U(T_1)\mathcal{\Psi}_1 = \mathcal{\Psi}_2$ where $\Psi_2 \in \mathcal{R}_2$.

But, when we look at **Section 2.3**, he considers a symmetry tranformation on "spacetime" $$x^\mu \mapsto \Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu + a^\mu$$ (the standard Lorentz transformation) and infers on *Pg.57* that by [Wigner's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner's_theorem) this induces a unitary transformation $U(\Lambda,a)$ such that $\Psi \mapsto U(\Lambda,a)\Psi$. As per the first point, doesn't the Wigner's theorem just say for transformation on Rays and not spacetime? Arn't these two completely different spaces, respectively the Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$ and 4-D Real space $\mathcal{R}^4$

**My Doubt:**

The above statements has put me in a fix! As per my understanding of the Hilbert space, it a infinite dimensional vector space that facilitates the existence of physical state vectors such as the position,momentum,spin, etc. as $|x,p,s,..\rangle$.

Do they mean that the space time transformation induces a transformation on the rays $|x^\mu,p,s,..\rangle$ of Hilbert space  as $$T_1|x^\mu,p,s,..\rangle \mapsto |\Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu + a^\mu,p,s,..\rangle$$ and therefore, my wigners theorem, there exists a unitary matrix such that the above two are related as $$U(\Lambda,a)|x^\mu,p,s,..\rangle \mapsto |\Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu + a^\mu,p,s,..\rangle$$

If the above is the case, my understanding would be right. Could someone heck if this is what it means? On a side note, when we say $U(\Lambda,a)$ is a transformation relating two Hilbert spaces, aren't both the Hilbert spaces the same? Just the basis in a sense changes right? If not, can you give examples/ understanding how 2 Hilbert spaces can be different?

Comment: *"As per my understanding of the Hilbert space, it a **finite** dimensional vector space"* [emph. mine] No. The Hilbert spaces of quantum mechanics are typically infinite-dimensional. And yes, the rest of what you say is mostly correct. Please don't ask question that merely ask for checking your understanding, because *"That's right"* is too short to even post as an answer.

Comment: Hello, It was a typo, I meant infinite dimesional. Well, I wanted to see if that's what is means. But the last part of the answer. What about that? I dont see a difference between 2 hilbert spaces but I'm sure I've come across it in textbooks where they look at maps between 2 hilbert spaces.in the context of QM.

Comment: All separable Hilbert spaces are abstractly isomorphic. From that point of view, there'd only ever be one Hilbert space. Being isomorphic as Hilbert space doesn't mean you cannot write down *different objects*, which may be isomorphic as Hilbert spaces, but are surely not the same object.